# Regarding serialize hibernate object to json using Gson

Tags: java, json, hibernate, serialization, gson

I m trying to serialize hibernate object to json with the use of **Gson** library.I had to implement **custom Type Adapter** in this case because GSon can't serialize HibernateProxy objects in normal manner.I tried to implement the **TypeAdapter** as I can use with any object type without modifying it .

> Here is my TypeAdapter class :

```
public class CustomTypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Object> {

@Override
public JsonElement serialize(Object object, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsc) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    try {
        Map<String, String> properties = BeanUtils.describe(object);
        //org.apache.commons.beanutils
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
            jsonObject.addProperty(entry.getKey(),  entry.getValue());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
    }

}
```

But the problem I have got is the inner objects are not going to serialize with this implementation. It is just returns the address of the object.(Product@54554356)

```
List<ProductHasSize> phsList = s.createCriteria(ProductHasSize.class, "phs")
                .createAlias("phs.product", "product")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("product.id", 1))
                .list();
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(ProductHasSize.class, new CustomTypeAdapter()).create();
        String element = gson.toJson(phsList);
        response.getWriter().write(element);
```

> Current Out-put :

```
[{"product":"com.certus.dbmodel.Product@54554356","size":"com.certus.dbmodel.Size@215a88a","price":"1250.0","qnty":"20","id":"1","class":"class com.certus.dbmodel.ProductHasSize"},{"product":"com.certus.dbmodel.Product@54554356","size":"com.certus.dbmodel.Size@2eab455a","price":"1300.0","qnty":"5","id":"2","class":"class com.certus.dbmodel.ProductHasSize"}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

BeanUtils.describe does not provide enough information. It will be fine if all types are primitive.

You will have to serialize each property independently. For fields that are not primitive types, serialize them. You also have to create the adapter for the actual type, so you can access its properties.

```
public class CustomTypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<ProductHasSize> {

@Override
public JsonElement serialize(ProductHasSize phs, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsc) {

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
//    try {
//        Map<String, String> properties = BeanUtils.describe(object);
//        //org.apache.commons.beanutils
//        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
//            jsonObject.addProperty(entry.getKey(),  entry.getValue());
//        }
//    } catch (Exception ex) {
//        ex.printStackTrace();
//    }
    jsonObject.addProperty("price", phs.getPrice());
    jsonObject.addProperty("quantity", phs.getQuantity());
    JsonElement jsonProduct = jsc.serialize(phs.getProduct());
    jsonObject.add("product", jsonProduct);
    JsonElement jsonSize = jsc.serialize(phs.getSize());
    jsonObject.add("size", jsonSize);

    return jsonObject;
    }

}
```

This page has a nice introduction: http://www.javacreed.com/gson-serialiser-example/